# Some keys not functioning consistently

Tags: keyboard

The following keys  are not working consistently on my keyboard: <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd>

There are times that I have to press them repeatedly before it works. Other times, they work effortlessly with normal pressure.

Does it probably just need cleaning, or is there a software/hardware issue?

I was hoping there's a way to fix this without having to go to a service center or replace the keys (I kind of don't know how to either, afraid I might damage it altogether), so thank you for your help!

I'm running Windows 7 on an MSI CX41 laptop.